# Delete Values from NSDictionary for which Key is Empty String

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am getting JSON response like this :

```
{
    "partner_wise": {
        “partner1”: {
            "processing": 254,
            "complete": 0,
            "track_invoice": 0,
            "bar_code": 0
       },
        "": {
            "processing": 0,
            "complete": 0,
            "track_invoice": 0,
            "bar_code": 0
             },
        "partner2": {
            "processing": 0,
            "complete": 0,
            "track_invoice": 0,
            "bar_code": 0
        }
      }
}
```

I am setting these values indexwise in tableView. From this JSON Response I didn't have to show the value for which key is empty string. How can I delete this object from NSDictionary.

Comment: BTW the `key` is neither `NULL` nor `nil`. It is an empty string.

Comment: Yes, I edited question for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete these objects from NSDictionary. NSDictionary is a immutable object.
But you can make a mutable copy and remove unneeded keys:

```
//remove from mutable dictionary
NSDictionary* dictionary = [self getData];
NSMutableDictionary* mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
[mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@""];
self.data = mutableDictionary;
```

Comment: fix has to be made in server . No object should return with empty string .

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `removeObjectForKey`

```
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:@""];
```

Example Code:

```
//your json dictionary here!
NSDictionary *finalDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"11111111",@"",@"00000000",@"testkey1", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryColection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:finalDictionary];
NSLog(@"Dictionary Full: %@", dictionaryColection);

[dictionaryColection removeObjectForKey:@""];
finalDictionary = dictionaryColection;
NSLog(@"Final dictionary removed: %@", finalDictionary);
```

Logs:

```
Dictionary Full: {
    "" = 11111111;
    testkey1 = 00000000;
}

Final dictionary removed: {
    testkey1 = 00000000;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In swift 3.0

`dictionary.removeObject(forKey: "")`

Comment: I would love to know the reason too, unfortunately, people have the power to downvote anything and go away without any possible reasoning.

Comment: I was also going to downvote, but the comments caught my eyes, this answers ressembles tons of low quality answers we recieve. If you want to avoid downvote misconception, put a little effort, provide some description and logic, at least make it look legit.

Comment: @LalKrishna This answer describes nothing. `removeObjectForKey` answer has already given. Just converting the single line in `swift` doesn't make sense. Also there is no tag for `swift` in question so this become useless here.